# Create a markdown with a list plots as a carousel instead of one one top of each other

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hi I have markdown with a list of plots that I would like to have it be plotted in a single area that can be scroll from left to right. I tried using slickR but the images are blank.

Here is a reproducible code.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(slickR)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
```

```{r fig=TRUE,fig.width=20, fig.height=14, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, results='asis' }


ggplot_list <- list(
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 1"),
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 2"),
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 3")
)

# Convert ggplots to plotly 
plotly_list <- lapply(ggplot_list, plotly::plotly_build)

# Create a carousel using slickR
carousel_content <- tagList(lapply(plotly_list, function(p) {
  tags$div(style = "width:100%;height:400px;", p)
}))


# simulate loop - imagine if there were two list of plots 
for ( n in 1:2 ) {
slickR::slickR(carousel_content, height = 400)%>%
    print
}

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with the **swipeR** package.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2023-05-05"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, collapse = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(swipeR)
library(htmltools)
library(base64enc)
```

```{r}
g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 1")
g2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 2")
g3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 3")
ggsave("g1.png", g1)
ggsave("g2.png", g2)
ggsave("g3.png", g3)
g1b64 <- dataURI(file = "g1.png", mime = "image/png")
g2b64 <- dataURI(file = "g2.png", mime = "image/png")
g3b64 <- dataURI(file = "g3.png", mime = "image/png")
```

```{r}
wrapper <- swipeRwrapper(
  tags$img(src = g1b64, style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;"),
  tags$img(src = g2b64, style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;"),
  tags$img(src = g3b64, style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;")
)
swipeR(wrapper, height = "400px", navigationColor = "navy")
```
````

[image]

---

## Edit

I forgot you want **plotly** graphics. This is even easier:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2023-05-05"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, collapse = TRUE)
library(plotly)
library(swipeR)
library(htmltools)
```

```{r}
g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 1")
g2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 2")
g3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 3")
```

```{r}
wrapper <- swipeRwrapper(
  tags$div(style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;", ggplotly(g1)),
  tags$div(style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;", ggplotly(g2)),
  tags$div(style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;", ggplotly(g3))
)
swipeR(wrapper, height = "400px", navigationColor = "navy")
```
````

[image]

Comment: this is fantastic,  do you know how to get it to print when in a loop? For example when Id this it failed to print any plots. ```for ( i in 1:2){
swipeR(wrapper, height = "400px", navigationColor = "navy")  %>% print 
}```

Comment: @Ahdee Not sure to follow you. But I think you can construct the wrapper with `do.call`.